# asp.net menuitem add class

Tags: asp.net

hi all I have a MenuItem that im dynamically adding childrent to using the following code

```
MenuItem c1 = new MenuItem("text","value");
parent.ChildItems.Add(c1);
```

however I need to add a css class to it at the the same time something like

```
c1.cssClass = "cssclass";
or 
c1.attributes.Add("Class","cssclass");
```

does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MenuItem` doesn't have a CSS class property, instead add the class to the parent `Menu`:

```
Menu menu = new Menu();
menu.CssClass = "myclass";
```

If you want to dynamically add classes to the menu then try creating a helper method ([Extension Methods in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31050/String-Extension-Collection-for-C)):

```
public static class MenuExtension
{
    public static void AddCSSClass(this Menu menu, string className)
    {
        // additional code here to tidy / remove duplicates etc.

        menu.CssClass = string.Concat(menu.CssClass, " ", className);
    }
}
```

Since our `Menu` renders a `UL` you can then use CSS selectors to cascade the style to all child `LI` elements:

```
.myclass > li {
    // your attributes
}
```

Or alternatively, specific `LI` elements (things like nth-child etc are only supported in CSS 3.0):

```
.myclass > li:first-child {
    // your attributes
}

.myclass > li:nth-child(1) {
    // your attributes
}
```

Comment: brilliant thanks not perfect but ive worked out a way to do it using jquery $('.regionkeyaudtolong ul li ul li:nth-child(5)').addClass('tolong');

Comment: @andrewslaughter good stuff, you could also use the `eq` in jQuery instead of `nth-child` - `$('.regionkeyaudtolong ul li ul li').eq(5).addClass('tolong');`

Answer (score -1):

You can try with `MenuItemStyle property` of your menu

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitemstyle.aspx